# ion auth how to handle access via groups and permissions

Tags: php, codeigniter, roles, usergroups, ion-auth

I am looking to use Ion Auth as an authentication library in one of my newer projects but I cant seem to understand how to handle permissions to perform certain actions.

For example, I have deals and items and a group "A" which can update both deals and items, and a group "B" which can only update items. How do I code this to make it work?

doing something like this:

```
//updating deals and items
if($user->in_group('A') || $user->in_group('B')){
    // ok so hes got permission to do it.
}
```

seems like a very bad approach since this is something that should be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is what is called an ACL (Access Control List), which is not the same as an authentication library & is not included in ion_auth by design

You can google around for a good library you like

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I diddnt know that. Instead of using another ACL, I simply extended ion_auth library (with a bunch of hacks since CI unfortunately dosent support extending libraries). Since ion_auth already had 'groups', all I had to do was add a permissions table and do a many-to-many join with groups table (and obviously add a few functions to the library)

Comment: CI is just php, and so supports extending classes just fine - that is the recommended way of adding on to Ion Auth or anything else. Glad you got it to work out